# Free satellite image for image segmentation testing

Tags: image-segmentation, satellite-image

I need some free satellite images (panchromatic) to test some segmentation algorithms.

I have searched the web but I didn't find any resources our websites that provide free satellite images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill this form and request for a free samples from Geoeye of IKONOS imagery.

http://www.geoeye.com/corpsite/solutions/learn-more/sample-imagery.aspx

or alternatively GLCF has 4 IKONOS images samples that can be used. You can download them from here:
http://glcf.umd.edu/data/ikonos/

Note: IKONOS 2 has 4 multi-spectral bands of 4m resolution and 1 panchromatic band of 1m resolution. You can just use the Panchromatic band if that is your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

## General search engines of satellite granules

You can search and download Landsat images from [Earthexplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or [Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) services. You'll find several collections there.

## Landsat panchromatic

Landsat ETM+ provide a panchromatic image at band 8 with 15m resolution. One example [here](http://glovis.usgs.gov/ImgViewer/showmetadata.cgi?scene_id=LE70290302013073EDC00), from WRS-2 Path 29 row 30.

## LDCM misson

Be aware that Landsat [LDCM mission](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/landsat/main/index.html) scenes will be available soon at the same website, by the end of May.